# Typescript -w(watch) is not working in my installation

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typescript2.0

I have installed the Typescript 2.0.6, i am also having the node installation. If i try to compile a file in watch mode with "-w" it is not working. It throws the below error.

```
ts5001: the current host does not support the '--watch' option
```

Used the below command to compile my typescript file "index.ts"

```
tsc -w index.ts
```

If any know please help me how to compile the code in watch mode.

Answer (score 1):

### Updated answer for 2021

There is a built in `--watch` / `-w` option see [the TS compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) (at the very end of the list).

Or once you have `tsconfig.json` setup with the `outDir` and `rootDir`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig.json to read more about this file */

    /* Basic Options */
    // "incremental": true,  /* Enable incremental compilation */
    "target": "ES2020",     /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "ES2020",   /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */
    "outDir": "src/main/resources/static/js",  /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    "rootDir": "src/main/resources/static/ts" /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
  }
}
```

Then you can just call

```
tsc --watch
```

This second option isn't one I've tried yet personally, but it's another option for file watching see [Configuring Watch](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/configuring-watch.html) for more details, but here is their example `tsconfig.json` setup given from official site:

> ```
> {   // Some typical compiler options   
>   "compilerOptions": {
>     "target": "es2020",
>     "moduleResolution": "node"
>     // ...   },
>
>   // NEW: Options for file/directory watching   "watchOptions": {
>     // Use native file system events for files and directories
>     "watchFile": "useFsEvents",
>     "watchDirectory": "useFsEvents",
>
>     // Poll files for updates more frequently
>     // when they're updated a lot.
>     "fallbackPolling": "dynamicPriority"   
>   } 
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get `watch` functionality by running typescript code by using `tsc`

Run it like
`node tsc.js -w  index.ts`

Source: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2375

Comment: Hi, i tried this option its throwing error.

      module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'F:\Build\MAS\Typescript\tsc.js'

Comment: Did you install tsc using npm ?

Comment: It comes with visual studio didn't install through npm.

Comment: If you're going to use node, we'd recommend you install TypeScript via npm and make sure that node's tsc comes before Visual Studio's tsc in your PATH.  **source: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2375**

Comment: Anyway i didn't install tsc with npm before install VS, what can i do now. How can i use node with tsc

Comment: Install tsc in a different location using node and in the PATH keep the location of this before the location of visual studio's tsc

Comment: If we install through npm it will take the path automatically right? How can we install in a particular location. Can you please give me some reference or command.

Comment: I don't understand this answer - what is `tsc.js`?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem and, for me, it was a matter of adding the correct route to my environment variables/PATH. Open up the "Developer Command Prompt" and type in "where tsc". You should get four different routes:

1) C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\3.0\tsc.exe

2) C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\3.0\tsc.js

3) C:\Users*yourUserName*\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc

4) C:\Users*yourUserName*\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc.cmd

My initial thought was to add the first one to my PATH, however the one you'll need in order to use "tsc -w" is actually the third one.

So add this to your PATH: C:\Users*yourUserName*\AppData\Roaming\npm\

If this was your issue, you should be all set.

Answer (score 0):

This is the work around works for me:

- install typescript locally by running `npm -i typescript`
- Add `npm` task which runs the `watch` script to `tasks.json` (see below)
- Add the `watch` script to `packages.json` (see below)

**The task to be added to `tasks.json`:**

`{
        "type": "npm",
        "script": "watch"
}`

**The script to be added to `packages.json`**

```
"watch": "node ./node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc -w"
```