# TypeScript Watch Option Not Working Windows 10 Command Line

Tags: typescript, windows-10

I am simply trying to execute the code that watches a file from a Windows terminal:

```
tsc -w .\app.ts
```

I receive the message:

```
error TS5001: The current host does not support the --watch option.
```

Now I have researched other solutions, and one that I saw GitHub said to try something like this because apparently tsc.exe does not implement file watching, while node.js does.

```
node tsc.js -w app.ts
```

But that returned another error message:

```
module.js:487 throw error; 
Error: Cannot find module 'C:.\..\tsc.js
```

What do I need to do to get beyond this issue?

Comment: The initial error seems to be complaining that (mysteriously) Windows 10 [*does not support `--watch`*](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/f35a20e29e3f74e5c049855db05471430368ce49/src/compiler/tsc.ts#L118). I don't believe that changing the way you invoke it will change the underlying support.

Comment: Digging a bit more, that's seems to be just a wrapper for [`fs.Watch`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener) which ought to be supported (if your system supports [`ReadDirectoryChangesW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365465%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). What version of Node.js are you running?

Comment: Thanks msanford for responding.  I tried to re-invoke it another way because I read tsc.exe, is a Javascript runner, the "host", for the TypeScript compiler which is tsc.js apparently.  I read that it is tsc.exe, that does not implement file watching, but as we know, node does.

Comment: Aside: I was two steps away from answering exactly the same thing as the other answerer (who deleted their response) until I read the source for `tsc.js`. Also, is [this bug useful](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15328) (are you up-to-date with Windows and all your dependencies?)

Comment: I ran into this issue and posted an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52225019/7960325